Save session information in Postgres with cutom Session model for express
I want to use session for an express back-end authentication & authorization using express-session library. I also want to persist the session in Postgres with custom schema as defined in the Prisma schema below.
model session {
  id        String   @id @default(uuid())
  userId    String
  ipAddress String?
  userAgent String?
  expiresAt DateTime
  createdAt DateTime @default(now())
  updatedAt DateTime @updatedAt
  User      Users    @relation(fields: [userId], references: [id])
}

What is the correct way to persist sessions in the database with custom schema?
I tried using connect-pg-simple but I believe it does not allow custom schema (model) for session. So should I just manually implement a way to work with sessions with Postgres and not use express-session and connect-pg-simple or am I missing something?
